# XSL Transformation - passing map as parameter to response xsl and iterate to add a new element displaying the key value

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, key-value

I'm a beginner to XSLT and need help to fix an issue. I'm passing hashmap as a parameter to xsl.

Hashmap is in this format {3=2021-06-09,2=2021-05-16,1=2021-05-13}. [seqNo-Date]

Currently I have output response like this

```
<response>
<result>
<repo>
<source>sim</source>
<confirmationNo>123</confirmationNo>
</repo>
<seqNo>1</seqNo>
</result>
<result>
<repo>
<source>car</source>
<confirmationNo>456</confirmationNo>
</repo>
<seqNo>2</seqNo>
</result>
<response>
```

But I need to add a new element in the xml based on the key(seqNo) here. That means, I need the response to look like this. Date is the new element added to response based on the seqno in the map. Seq. no is the key and date is the map.

```
<response>
<result>
<repo>
<source>sim</source>
<confirmationNo>123</confirmationNo>
<date>2021-05-13</date>
</repo>
<seqNo>1</seqNo>
</result>
<result>
<repo>
<source>car</source>
<confirmationNo>456</confirmationNo>
<date>2021-05-16</date>
</repo>
<seqNo>2</seqNo>
</result>
<response>
```

Can someone please suggest how to do this by reading the map in xsl 1.0. I tried to use map.get() function but it didnt work. Please help.

Comment: In which programming language do you have the map and which XSLT processor do you use?

Comment: Your example hash-parameter contains 3 pairs of  a sequence and a date. In your response I only see 2 being used. Is that correct? And where does the other data come from. Could you show that xml-source?

Comment: Basically, there can be 'n' no. of seq no's and corresponding dates in the map. And, based on  the sequence no., I need to be able to dynamically populate the date value in the new 'element'. And, I'm using the XSLT 1.0 processor.

Comment: map is updated using Java

Comment: In the Java world I would suggest to move to Saxon 9 or 10 as an XSLT 3.0 processor instead of relying on the old, built-in XSLT 1.0 support.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to achieve this in xslt 1.0 and I’m clueless on how to achieve that. Since the map is dynamic and the corresponding date had to be added to response xml for each seq.

Answer (score 0):

> how to do this by reading the map in xsl 1.0.

Consider the following example:

**XML**

```
<response>
    <result>
        <repo>
            <source>sim</source>
            <confirmationNo>123</confirmationNo>
        </repo>
        <seqNo>1</seqNo>
    </result>
    <result>
        <repo>
            <source>car</source>
            <confirmationNo>456</confirmationNo>
        </repo>
        <seqNo>2</seqNo>
    </result>
</response>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="map">3=2021-06-09,2=2021-05-16,1=2021-05-13</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="/response">
    <response>
        <xsl:for-each select="result">
            <result>
                <repo>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="repo/*"/>
                    <date>
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(concat(',', $map, ','), concat(',', seqNo, '=')), ',')"/>
                    </date>
                </repo>
                <xsl:copy-of select="seqNo"/>
            </result>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </response>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <result>
    <repo>
      <source>sim</source>
      <confirmationNo>123</confirmationNo>
      <date>2021-05-13</date>
    </repo>
    <seqNo>1</seqNo>
  </result>
  <result>
    <repo>
      <source>car</source>
      <confirmationNo>456</confirmationNo>
      <date>2021-05-16</date>
    </repo>
    <seqNo>2</seqNo>
  </result>
</response>
```

Answer (score 0):

How you pass external parameters into a transformation depends a lot on which XSLT processor you are using, and unfortunately you haven't told us this.

XSLT 3.0 has a native map type, which would make your life easier.

But with XSLT 1.0, I would generally choose to pass this data in as XML, not as a string. You're working in a world designed on the assumption that structured data is represented in XML, not in some micro syntax that you've invented for yourself.

Comment: I apologize, I'm trying to use XSLT 1.0

Comment: No need to apologise, you said you were a beginner and beginners are often unaware of the features of different versions. I just like you to know that if you're using 1.0, you're missing out on a lot of cool features!